# How to edit bbPress template files - WordPress + BuddyPress + bbPress?

Tags: theme-development, functions, buddypress, child-theme, bbpress

I am using BuddyPress 1.6.1, bbPress 2.1.2 and WordPress 3.4.2

I follow the guide [here](http://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/installing-group-and-sitewide-forums/).

In the end, I did the trick pointed out by [Sarah Gooding](http://wpmu.org/how-to-make-your-wordpress-theme-compatible-with-buddypress/) because mywebsite.com/forums was blank right after the above installation

- Created a page called "Forums" with permalink mywebsite.com/forums
- Insert bbPress shortcode [bbp-forum-index] into "Forums" page

My questions are

1) How do I customise page templates for the forum e.g. Forum page, topic page etc.

My current theme is a child theme of twentyeleven and it has the following structure

> themes/bp-twentyeleven/
>
> ```
> /activity/
>
> /blogs/
>
> /forums/
>
>     index.php
>
>     forums-loop.php
>
> /groups/
>
> /members/
>
> /registration/
>
> header.php
>
> sidebar.php
>
> style.css
> ```

*Notes*

- Apparently, bp-twentyevelen/forums/index.php is being ignored.
- The reason for this set up is that I need the site to looks like TwentyEleven and has BuddyPress' functionality at the same time

2) How do I make sure that bbPress functions will work for my site e.g. do I copy and past all the functions in functions.php of bbPress' default theme over my theme's functions.php?

3) How do I ensure that whatever I will get from 1) and 2) (probably from bbPress experts somewhere) will not conflict with BuddyPress' functionality or my theme?

BuddyPress setting screenshots are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2wL1.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPkTK.png).
bbPress settings screenshot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFpbj.png).

Comment: 1 week past and no answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for myself actually.

Yes, I love the fact that bbPress is not obtrusive!
It almost doesn’t matter at all how I am trying integrate BuddyPress here.

So this narrow downs to customise bbPress template when installed as a plugin to WordPress.
The answer is here: http://codex.bbpress.org/legacy/step-by-step-guide-to-creating-a-custom-bbpress-theme/

Thanks for [Zaerl on bbPress support forums](http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/how-to-edit-bbpress-template-files-wordpress-buddypress-bbpress/).